# zabbix connectio to external database

Tags: database, mariadb, zabbix, failover

I am trying to setup zabbix with two database , one on localhost and another on diffrent machine.

zabbix server: 192.168.0.100
external database :192.168.0.154

I setup zabbix with localhostdatabaase and its working perfectly,Then I created sql dump file and put it in external database ie,192.168.0.154, but when I change the database ip in zabbix frontend PHP file it gives me permission denied,Ihave created all the required user in external database ie, zabbix@192.168.0.100
and assigned it all the permission still its giving permission denied error, also I have edited zabbix_server.conf file. please help struggling from past 3 days.

Comment: looks like a network issue, please check if there's a firewall, and if you can find some error logs in the destination host

Comment: Have checked the network , everything is ok and also firewall is disabled in both machine, also selinux is also disabled, also checked mariadb logs but no useful data found

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on local databases. All I need to do was disabling selinux, configure firewall and change permissions to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.socket.
But in logs I had info about problem with this socket.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).